# Load credential from IAM role EC2 Instance instead of env in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm currently taking credential from env to take credential for bucket. The code currently I'm using is:

```
import  AWS  from "aws-sdk";

export const S3Bucket = (req, res) => {
  const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
  const IAM_USER_KEY = process.env.IAM_USER_KEY;
  const IAM_USER_SECRET = process.env.IAM_USER_SECRET;
  try {
    
  
  let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: IAM_USER_SECRET,
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
  });
  s3bucket.createBucket(() => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `path/${fileName}`,
        Body: JSON.stringify(data)
      };
      s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {

        if(!data) res.status(500).json(data);
        else
        res.status(200).json(data);
      });
  });
 } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

I'm looking for alternative code which should load credential from IAM role. I've tried reading documention but didn't get much insight.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assume the role and use the credentials from there provided you have access to assume the mentioned role. Something like below:

[sts_assumerole.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javascript-iam-sts_assumerole.js.html)

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

var roleToAssume = {RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RoleName',
                    RoleSessionName: 'session1',
                    DurationSeconds: 900,};
var roleCreds;

// Create the STS service object    
var sts = new AWS.STS({apiVersion: '2011-06-15'});

//Assume Role
sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else{
        roleCreds = {accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                     secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                     sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken};
        stsGetCallerIdentity(roleCreds);
    }
});

//Get Arn of current identity
function stsGetCallerIdentity(creds) {
    var stsParams = {credentials: creds };
    // Create STS service object
    var sts = new AWS.STS(stsParams);
        
    sts.getCallerIdentity({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data.Arn);
        }
    });    
}
```